# Datetime Field Received a Naive Datetime

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm running into the classic `DateTimeField received a naive datetime while time zone support is active` warning with a twist. The error occurs when I run tests that utilize factories provided by `factory_boy`. Here is an example of a factory:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
import factory
class PostFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Post
    value = 42
    created = now()
```

As you can see, I'm using the now() method from Django's timezone, which should take care of the whole naive datetime thing, but it doesn't. Here's what the model looks like:

```
class Post(models.Model)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Also, in my settings.py file, I have set `USE_TZ = True`.

I've tried installing `pytz` and using its libraries to create a datetime object to populate the field in the factory, but that doesn't work either.

I know I can suppress the warning, but it's already starting to bite me in other areas of the code, and I'd like to get to the bottom of it. . .

Comment: [`d.u.t.now()` returns an aware object if `USE_TZ=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now)

Comment: I know. That's why I'm confused by the error I'm getting, since I'm using d.u.t.now() to fill in the DateTimeField.

Comment: Are you sure this part of code gives you the warning?

Comment: I can't think of where else would if I'm just running tests and factory boy is the only thing populating the DB...

Comment: Hi, I was wondering you were able to fix this @user1427661

Answer (score 25):

You can use faker as follows:

```py
import factory
from django.utils import timezone


class PostFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = models.Post
    value = 42
    created = factory.Faker("date_time", tzinfo=timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `timezone` in `settings.py` also.

When `USE_TZ` is `False`, this is the time zone in which Django will store all datetimes. When `USE_TZ` is `True`, this is the default time zone that Django will use to display datetimes in templates and to interpret datetimes entered in forms.

Comment: forgot to mention, I have USE_TZ set to True already. Updated post to reflect that

Comment: It's not working. I just forgot to mention that the not working code already has USE_TZ set to True.